# How to use DelegateDecompiler computed properties with PredicateBuilder and child collections

Tags: .net, entity-framework, predicatebuilder

I'm using DelegateDecompiler with Entity Framework to add computed properties.  I'm also using PredicateBuilder to compose expressions for queries.

I'm having a problem getting the computed properties into SQL when using PredicateBuilder.

For Example:

*Get Parents whose children's FullName starts with A, where FullName is a computed property*

```
context.Parents.Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.Fullname.StartsWith("A"))).Decompile()
```

Works as desired.

I want to compose the Where Expression using [A universal PredicateBuilder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/) like so ...

```
var predicateParent = PredicateBuilder.True<ParentEntity>();
var predicateChild = PredicateBuilder.True<ChildEntity>();
predicateChild = predicateChild.And(c => c.FullName.StartsWith("A"));
predicateParent = predicateParent.And(x => x.Children.AsQueryable().Any(predicateChild));
var query = db.Parents.Where(predicateParent).Decompile();
List<ParentEntity> parents = query.ToList();
```

But it throws exception: *The specified type member 'FullName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.*

**How can the predicates be used with computed properties in children collection?**

Here are the entity classes.

```
    public class ParentEntity
    {
        public ParentEntity()
    {
        Children = new List<ChildEntity>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ChildEntity> Children { get; set; }

    [Computed]
    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
    }
}

public class ChildEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Computed]
    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
    }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual ParentEntity Parent { get; set; }
}

public class ParentChildModel: DbContext
{
    public ParentChildModel()
        : base("name=ParentChildModel")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<ParentEntity> Parents { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ChildEntity> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `AsQueryable()` and `Decompile()` don't play nice together. Maybe you should give Linqkit's predicate builder a try. (Although in general, I also prefer the one you use).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I tried LinqKit's predicate builder, but it didn't work.  However, LinqKit's Expand() extension did help.  I added .Expand() to the predicate in this line `var query = db.Parents.Where(predicateParent.Expand()).Decompile();` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add LinqKit's Expand() extension method to the constructed predicate like this.

```
var query = db.Parents.Where(predicateParent.Expand()).Decompile();
```

Thanks Gert for LinqKit suggestion, it got me close enough to stumble on the answer.